# How to integrate Spring batch command line invocation in a shell script

Tags: shell, spring-batch

I am having a spring batch application, that is invoked through the command line. I would want to put that invocation in a shell script, so that I can run a script rather than the entire command.

For example, my invocation looks like:

java -jar    run=1

The problem is for each run, the job parameter needs to be incremented. Is there a way through which i can achieve that in a shell script?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a persistence context (those tables with BATCH_ prefix) for your spring batch jobs?

Comment: yes we do have.. and thats the reason the job parameter needs to be passed and incremented (as it needs to be unique) each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an incrementer for this as usual.

```
<bean id="simpleIncrementer"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer"/>
<job id="myJob" incrementer="simpleIncrementer">
</job>
```

The trick for this incrementer to work with [CommandLineJobRunner](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html) is adding the **-next** parameter when running the task.

> -next: (optional) to start the next in a sequence according to the JobParametersIncrementer in the Job

Something like this:

```
java –jar myjob.jar jobs/myjob.xml myjob -next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it n times (in a terminal) using a for loop this way:

```
for i in {1..10}; do java -jar run=$i; done
```

Comment: Hi.. I am just wondering, that the value of 'i' needs to be changed each time i run the shell script.. so will the above work? For example, if i run the job 2 times...then exit the session... log in back again and re-run the shell script... will the varibale get incremented to 3 or will it be back again to 1 ?